# Regex to match given URL

Tags: django

Been stuck with this for a long time already. I have a URL like the following:

```
http://localhost:8000/foobar/0/ec8b6cf5203c6ce57521155fea4f96a53e0fadb5/
```

The last part of the URL is a SHA1 hex representation. My urls.py looks like this:

```
url(r'^/foobar/[0-9]/[a-z0-9]{40}/$', 'baz.views.foobar')
```

Could someone please help me spot why the URL isn't getting matched to this urls.py entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't try to match against the initial `/` - that's counted as part of the domain, or the previous urlconf if this is an include.